# Batch processing JS code on a Adobe PDF and saving result to a file or csv

Tags: javascript, adobe, batch-processing, acrobat

What I'd like to do is run a batch process on a bunch of PDF files in a folder. This process would execute a piece of javascript who's result would then be saved in a file/csv along with all of the other responses. Is doing something like this possible?

I've researched batch processes and I know how to create one but I can't figure out how to save data into a file using Adobe JS, and then save EVERY output from EVERY pdf into the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible... indirectly. Acrobat won't let you just write a CSV file out to disk. However, it will allow you to create a new PDF file and add the CSV ***string*** as a file attachment to it. You can then use JavaScript to export the attachment. Part of your batch script will be to open the PDF that holds the CSV output (the "storage" file), get the current CSV attachment as a string, append your data, save it back as an attachment and close the file. You will need to "disclose" the storage file in order to manipulate it via JavaScript from another file. That's all documented in the JavaScript API.